# Custom Line Layout of Abbreviations

Tags: context, acronyms

I've read the example in [\definesynonyms](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/definesynonyms) but can't seems what options should I use in [\setupsynonyms](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setupsynonyms) to get below output. There is a dash `-` betwen the abbreviation and the description.

[image]

Help is very much appreciate.

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want the coloured box as well? It is it only there to show the dashes?

Comment: Coloured box is the default rectangle colour scheme of Shutter screen capture tool. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know if there is an option explicit for this purpose, but you could use the `style` option to achieve this.

```
\definehspace[bbig][3.5em]
\definesynonyms[abbreviation][abbreviations][\infull]
\setupsynonyms[abbreviation][
    criterium=all, % place all abbreviations
    synonymstyle=normal, % style for e.g. \RFID{}
    textstyle=normal, % style for e.g. \infull{RFID}
    width=3.5em, % distance between abbreviation and synonym, default is 7em
    style={--\hspace[bbig]}, % style of synonym, inserted between abbreviation and synonym
]

\abbreviation{RF}{Radio-frequency}
\abbreviation{RFID}{Radio Frequency Indentification}
\abbreviation{UPC}{Universal Product Code}

\startdocument

\RFID{} is an abbreviation for \infull{RFID}

\startsubject[title={List of Synonyms}]
    \placelistofsynonyms[abbreviation]
\stopsubject

\stopdocument
```

I set the `width` option to half of its default value and added the other half after the dash using the `style` option.
[image]

Comment: lcxolu, you're a gentleman and a scholar. Thanks!